# Memory utiization

Tags: memory

I use free -m to check memory status.
In this pic [image]
we see total used & memory. I want the result in %. Like Used memory - total memory x by 100. And whenever I want to check the memory status, it should b shown in %

Comment: I use `htop` to monitor memory on my systems.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a short script to parse the output and divide the numbers. Some solutions can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585978/linux-command-for-percentage-of-memory-that-is-free

Just be careful. What exactly do you mean by "total used"? The first line (Mem) is not what you want... second line is better, because cached memory should count as free, not used. Then you also have to decide if Swap should be counted or not.

Comment: As shown in the picture, just look at the first 3 columns.
Total    Used    Free

I need a script in which used memory is divided by total memory and then multiply with 100. so that I can get the answer but in %.